# What does this line in DBI.pm do?

Tags: regex, perl

```
603   $dsn =~ s/^dbi:(\w*?)(?:\((.*?)\))?://i
                         or '' =~ /()/; # ensure $1 etc are empty if match fails
```

I don't understand what `$dsn =~ s/^dbi:(\w*?)(?:\((.*?)\))?://i` is for,even more doubt about `'' =~ /()/`,seems useless to me..

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes. If this had been comp.lang.perl.misc, ~5 people would have attempted to explain that monster of a regular expression instead of telling the OP to read the manuals.

Comment: I actually liked this question.  Although the comment should be sufficient to explain, it may still not be "plain as day" if the behavior of $1 after a failed match isn't understood.

Answer (score 4):

The first part is extracting two parts of the dsn string in the form:

dbi: *first match* ( *optional second match* ) :

These matches will be placed into `$1` and `$2` for the use in later code. The second part will only run if the match was unsuccessful. This is achieved by using `or` which will short-circuit (i.e. not execute) the second expression if the first one was successful.

As the comment says quite succinctly, it ensures that `$1`, `$2`, etc. are empty. Presumably so later code can check them and produce an appropriate error if they were not set (i.e. could not be extracted from the dsn string).

Answer (score 1):

Equals-tilde, or `=~`, is the [match operator](http://www.htmlite.com/perl025.php).

Try the following code -- put it in a file, make executable with `chmod +x`, and run it:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$mystring = "Perl rocks.";

if ($mystring =~ /rocks/) {
  print("Matches");
} else {
  print("No match");
}
```

It will output `Matches`.

As for your example, it checks if the connection string is in the correct format, and extracts the database name, etc:

```
print($dsn);

$dsn = "dbi:SQLPlatform:database_name:host_name:port";

$dsn =~ s/^dbi:(\w*?)(?:\((.*?)\))?://i
                             or '' =~ /()/; # ensure $1 etc are empty if match fails

print($dsn);
```

Ouptuts `database_name:host_name:port`.

Answer (score 1):

It's clear from the comments in the code:

```
602     # extract dbi:driver prefix from $dsn into $1
603     $dsn =~ s/^dbi:(\w*?)(?:\((.*?)\))?://i
604             or '' =~ /()/; # ensure $1 etc are empty if match fails
```

If you have problems understanding how `s//` and `m//` work see [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html) and [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html).

Answer (score 0):

If a capturing match fails $1 may still contain a value; the value of the last successful matching capture in the same dynamic scope, possibly from some other previous regexp.  It appears the author didn't want a failed match at this point to leave some value in $1 from a previous regexp.  To prevent this, he forced a "will always succeed" capturing match with nothing specified within the capturing parens.  That means that there will be a match, and a capture of the empty string.  In other words, $1 will now be empty rather than containing the match value from some previous successful match.

A more common idiom is simply to test for match success before executing whatever code will rely on $1's value, as in:

```
if( /(match)/ ) {
    say $1;
}
```

While that's often the simplest approach, unfortunately code sometimes is not simple, and forcing that test into some complex code may make a tricky section even harder to deal with.  That being the case, it may just be easier to ensure that $1 contains nothing after a failed match, rather than what it contained before the failed match.

I actually think that's a good question.  Finding documentation of the behavior of #$1 after a failed match isn't easy within the Perl POD.  I believe a more thorough explanation is found either in the camel book or the llama book.  But I don't have them at my fingertips right now to check.

Answer (score 0):

What is left out of the answers so far is the reason for that mysterious `or '' =~ /()/`. Without that bit of trickiness, $1 will be undefined if the match fails. The code is probably using $1 in a concatenation or a string shortly after this match. Doing this with $1 undefined will result in a "Use of uninitialized value $1 in concatenation (.) or string" warning if `use warnings` is in effect. With that `or '' =~ /()/` trickiness in play, $1 will be defined (but empty) should the regular expression fail to match. This keeps that code that uses $1 from spewing.

The comment `# ensure $1 etc are empty if match fails` is incorrect. Get rid of that 'etc' and the comment is correct. This action sets $1, and $1 only. This code does not set $2. $2 will be undefined if the regular expression does not match.